# Laravel 5 form submit creates an error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, forms, controller, routes, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5. When editing a form a get this error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

There are a few posts but I think it may be code specific. I'd rather not use the resource route methods if possible. Route:

```
    Route::get('profile/edit', array('as' => 'admin.profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit'));
    Route::post('profile/edit', array('as' => 'admin.profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update'));
```

The form is :

```
{!!Form::model($profile,array('method'=>'Patch','route' =>array('admin.profile.update'))) !!}
```

Controller:

```
public function update()
{
    $user_id=$this->user->id;
    $input=array_except(Input::all(),'_method');
    Profile::where('user_id','=',$user_id)->update($input);
    return Redirect::route('admin.profile.index');

}
```

Here is the error info:

```
n RouteCollection.php line 207
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 194
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 142
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Thanks any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change this:

```
Route::post('profile/edit', array(
  'as' => 'admin.profile.update', 
  'uses' => 'ProfileController@update'
));
```

To this:

```
Route::patch('profile/edit', array(
  'as' => 'admin.profile.update', 
  'uses' => 'ProfileController@update'
));
```

I think your form action may need a matching route verb

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#basic-routing

For the second issue:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update user_profile` set _method = PATCH, _token =
```

Add this to the top of your controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then update your method as so:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $this->user->id;

    $input = $request->except('_method', '_token');

    Profile::where('user_id','=', $user_id)->update($input);

    return Redirect::route('admin.profile.index');

}
```

Comment: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `user_profile` set `_method` = PATCH, `_token` = ...`  I get this now

Comment: I think it's because this `$input=array_except(Input::all(),'_method');` isn't doing what you want it to, then it's trying inserting it to the DB on the update. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: When `Route::post` is changed to `Route::patch` yes, it works. Could you please describe the cause and how it fixing the issue?

Comment: @mapmalith because the questioner specified the patch method in his form markup and needed an end point to match it.

Comment: @haakym the reason asking is I am using `<form action="{{ url('profile/update') }}" method="post">` and there the same **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** and your `Route::patch` solution solved the issue.

Comment: It could be a number of reasons... `patch` is technically linked to `update` so it could be something to do with that https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers. Are you using a resourceful controller and method spoofing: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing? I could make further guesses as to why it's working with `Route::patch`, but you're probably best creating your own question with your form markup from the blade file and a list of relevant routes related to `/profile` if it doesn't soon become clear.

Answer (score 0):

In my case works adding `protected $guarded = ['_token'];` in Model file.